# SOLR DIH: Executing a query based on the results of a splitBy operation

Tags: sql, solr, dih

I am trying to index a legacy mySQL database. (as in terrible normalization) It contains a releases table with a subject column that contains a comma delimited list of subject ids and a lookup table matching those ids to actual subject names. What I'm trying to do is retrieve both the id and the name for each subject into SOLR but it does not seem to be working.

Here is the relevant portion of my data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="release"
    query="SELECT
        distinct(rkey), subject
        FROM releases_info"
        transformer="RegexTransformer">
    <field column="rkey" name="id" />
    <field name="s" column="subject" splitBy="," />
    <entity name="subject_names" query="SELECT name FROM subjects WHERE id = '${release.subject}'">
        <field name="subjects" column="name" />
    </entity>
</entity>
```

While the splitBy is working fine and replacing the values of release.subject with the appropriate split array, I've tried various permutations for the second select query but it either fails or retrieves nothing. Any idea where I may have gone wrong?